# Import google calendar by CalendarView

Tags: android, calendarview

I wanted to know if it is possible to import the google calendar display on the application by CalendarView. Is there an example? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Android does not provide any intent for Google Calendar. Google Calendar is a seperate app on any android device. However you can use CalendarProvider apis to sync with google calendar and create your own calendar UI to display those events.

Comment: Can I sync my calendar which is then visible to all?